# How can I change 'no rows to show' text programmatically in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, overlay, ag-grid

I have recently been tinkering with the Ag-grid . I want to change the 'no rows to show' text to 'data is loading...' , when I am fetching some data from the REST API . The data is being returned in the form of an array of JSON objects . However , if and when the API does return me an empty array , I want the 'Data is loading...' text to change to 'no rows to show' text.How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: show the code..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This can be done by working with both the `overlayLoadingTemplate` and `overlayNoRowsTemplate` input binding property, as described on the [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-overlays/#custom-templates).

On your component.html, you will need to add it to your ag-grid selector,

```
<ag-grid-angular
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  [overlayLoadingTemplate]="loadingTemplate"
  [overlayNoRowsTemplate]="noRowsTemplate"
        .
        .
></ag-grid-angular>
```

And on your component.ts, you can set the no rows template. First, we define a new property called `noRowsTemplate`, which was assigned to `overlayNoRowsTemplate` on the html. Then, you pass the html string that represents your custom message to noRowsTemplate.

```
export class AppComponent {
  private noRowsTemplate;
  private loadingTemplate;

  constructor() {
    this.loadingTemplate =
      `<span class="ag-overlay-loading-center">data is loading...</span>`;
    this.noRowsTemplate =
      `"<span">no rows to show</span>"`;
  }
}
```

Here is the [demo](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/BEJfOcosh4ZUHKgQ).

Comment: No need to put double quotes after first span: `"<span">no rows to show</span>"`, Just outer `"<span>no rows to show</span>"` works.

Comment: I didn't need to include a `<span>` at all either, just a string worked for me.