# Ag-grid change "No data to display" message

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Is it possible to change "No data to display" message shown on Ag-grid? I would like to set it to another custom message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change 'no rows to show' text programmatically in ag-grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55739686/how-can-i-change-no-rows-to-show-text-programmatically-in-ag-grid)

Comment: No, unfortunately it does not. It just adds an overlay on top of the grid. I would like to change the message without adding the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [localeText](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grid-options/#reference-localisation)

Check all [locale data(en)](https://www.ag-grid.com/examples/localisation/localisation/locale.en.js)

##### Example:

```js
// Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/V5M8va7pvVp0IH61?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div class="example-wrapper">
    <ag-grid-angular
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [localeText]="localeText"
      [rowData]="rowData"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
  </div>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  private gridApi!: GridApi<IOlympicData>;

... 
  
  public localeText: { [key: string]: string } = {
  noRowsToShow: "No data to display"
  }
```

Hope it helps!